# how to insert hidden input value into database in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have created the form with the help of model. And i have created hidden input value manually in django form with the syntax below

```
 <input type="hidden" value="123" name="fourth" />
```

My django html page look like this

first.html

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    {{form.first}}
    {{form.second}}
    {{form.third}}
    <input type="hidden" value="123" name="fourth"/>
 </form>
```

The problem is when form submission i can get the value of first,second,third and can insert the value using **form.save()**. But i can't able to insert value of fourth. Because i created **hidden input value manually**. How can i insert fourth value into database. Plz anyone help me to do this.

My table column:
first second third fourth

Comment: make sure you name the hidden field using the same naming convention Django uses for the other fields. Inspect the source of the page in the browser. What are the fields `first`, `second`, `third` named (and id)?

Comment: We don't know how your form and model looks like. Can you provide them?

Answer (score 3):

There is 2 different *form variables* there:

- Django form fields  (*first, second, third*)
- *raw* form fields (*fourth*)

To retrieve the Django form fields I supose you are using something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    field_name = form.cleaned_data['field_name'].
```

To get the raw field *fourth* you only need to access the *request.POST* like:

```
yourVar = request.POST['fourth']

# I'm used to the  'get' method like
yourVar = request.POST.get('fourth', '')
```

The last instruction `request.POST.get('fourth', '')` is used to avoid an error if there is no 'fourth' key within `request.POST`

## EDIT: Add non-form-field to database

I 'assume' that you're using some kind of model form and you want to create the instance when you do `form.save()` but you need to add the hidden field *fourth* to the instance, to do so you can do it like:

```
instance = form.save()
instance.fourth_field = request.POST.get('fourth', '')
instance.save()
```

I think this could return error if the `fourth_field` is required in the model, to avoid this you could do something like:

```
if form.is_valid():  # This statement cleans all fields

   field1 = form.cleaned_data['first']
   field2 = form.cleaned_data['second']
   field3 = form.cleaned_data['third']
   field4 = request.POST.get('fourth', '')

   instance = YourModel(first=first, second=second, third=third, fourth=fourth)
   instance.save()
```